# If ('something inside the array is typed down') {execute code}

Tags: javascript

I tried serveral things already and searched on this website and do not doubt that this question has already be answered alot of times, but I still don't get it.

What I'm trying to do with onkeyup is recognising what's being typed down.
Once something is typed down and matches a country inside the array that I created, it should do something like print out text to the browser/screen.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type='text' id='selectCountry' onkeyup='myFunction()'></input>



<script>
var countries = ['England', 'Netherlands', 'Germany'];

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Something like this? http://codepen.io/Agonn/pen/koifc

Comment: I'm trying to make it that once I type something down inside the <input type=text> tag and it's also inside the array, it will do something like print text to the screen.

Comment: Got it. If you'd like to write some text (not only console.log) you can do it like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aORyop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use innerHTML in order to show the text on the screen.

```js
var countries = ['England', 'Netherlands', 'Germany'];

function myFunction() {
  var value = document.getElementById('selectCountry').value,
    node = document.getElementById('output');
  while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
    node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    if (value === countries[i]) {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Found it!';
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <input type='text' id='selectCountry' onkeyup='myFunction()'></input>
  <p id="output"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var countries = ['England', 'Netherlands', 'Germany'];
function myFunction() {
  var value = document.getElementById('selectCountry').value;

  for(var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    if(value === countries[i]) { 
      console.log('found it!');
      break;
    }
  }

}
</script>

<input type='text' id='selectCountry' onkeyup='myFunction()'></input>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inputs can be changed in other ways than the keyboard, so better listen to `input` event.

Then, you can use `indexOf` to check if the value is in the array:

```js
document.getElementById('selectCountry').oninput = function() {
  if(countries.indexOf(this.value) >= 0) /* ... */
};
```

```js
var countries = ['England', 'Netherlands', 'Germany'];
document.getElementById('selectCountry').oninput = function() {
  if(countries.indexOf(this.value) >= 0) alert('match');
};
```

```html
<input type='text' id='selectCountry' />
```